# Codegen and Graphql-Request Error: Server Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')

Tags: react-hooks, graphql, server-error, codegen, graphql-request

[This is the Error image im getting when I start my frontend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M2yV.png)

Server Error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.

I am building a Full stack App using NextJs,GraphQL and codegen. When i run the frontend , it shows me the above error i have been trying to fix it but not able to do it.

I tried altering thte server and queries of graphql , not able to get the frontend , shows useState error but i am not using useState in my frontend.

Expected: Frontend landing page has to be viewed properly and allow for authentication using gogle.

Comment: Please include the code that led to this error.